# Keypoints matching But how to position the match

Tags: opencv, position

I have used ORB in OpenCV to make matches of keypoints between source image(which I want to position) and dst image(which the source image could be in). Now my problem is I have got some good matches, but how can I position the source image in the dst image?

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

My code is here, I have used findHomography(), but it can not find the correct object, even can not draw a quadrangle. Help me find my errors.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cv::Mat object = cv::imread("card.jpg");
    cv::VideoCapture mCapture;  
    cv::Mat scene;  
    mCapture.open(0);  
    assert(mCapture.isOpened());  
    while (1)  
    {  
        mCapture >> scene;  
        if (!scene.empty())  
        {  
           // ORB
            cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector;
            cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;

            //Find keypoints
            cv::Mat descriptorsA, descriptorsB;
            std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypointsA, keypointsB;
            //int64 last = cv::getTickCount();
            detector.detect(object, keypointsA);
            detector.detect(scene, keypointsB);
            //printf("detection = %f[s]\n", (cv::getTickCount() - last)/cv::getTickFrequency());
            //last = cv::getTickCount();
            extractor.compute(object, keypointsA, descriptorsA);
            extractor.compute(scene, keypointsB, descriptorsB);
            //printf("description = %f[s]\n", (cv::getTickCount() - last)/cv::getTickFrequency());

            // Match
            std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
            cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING, true);
            matcher.match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB, matches);

            // min distance
            double min_dist = DBL_MAX;
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)matches.size(); i++)
            { 
                double dist = matches[i].distance;
                if (dist < min_dist) 
                    min_dist = dist;
            }
            if (min_dist < 1.0) 
                min_dist = 1.0;
            //std::cout<<min_dist<<std::endl;
            // save good matches
            const double threshold = 1.5 * min_dist;
            std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches_good;
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)matches.size(); i++) 
            {
                if (matches[i].distance < threshold) 
                {
                    matches_good.push_back(matches[i]);
                }
            }

            // show
            Mat matchImage;

            // localize points
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> object_points, scene_points;
            for( int i = 0; i < matches_good.size(); i++ )
            {
                //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
                object_points.push_back( keypointsA[ matches_good[i].queryIdx ].pt );
                scene_points.push_back( keypointsB[ matches_good[i].trainIdx ].pt );
            }
            Mat H = findHomography(object_points, scene_points,  CV_RANSAC); 
            cv::drawMatches(object, keypointsA, scene, keypointsB, matches, matchImage, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1), std::vector<char>(), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

            std::vector<cv::Point2f> object_corners(4), scene_corners(4);
            object_corners[0] = cv::Point(0, 0),
            object_corners[1] = cv::Point(object.cols, 0);
            object_corners[2] = cv::Point(object.cols, object.rows);
            object_corners[3] = cv::Point(0, object.rows);
            cv::perspectiveTransform(object_corners, scene_corners, H);
            Mat diff;
            //diff = Mat(scene_corners) - Mat(scene_points);
            //cv::imshow("Diff",diff);
            // draw bounds
            cv::line(matchImage, scene_corners.at(0) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners.at(1) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
            cv::line(matchImage, scene_corners.at(1) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners.at(2) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
            cv::line(matchImage, scene_corners.at(2) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners.at(3) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
            cv::line(matchImage, scene_corners.at(3) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners.at(0) + cv::Point2f(object.cols, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

            cv::imshow("match", matchImage);
            //std::cout<<"match size:"<<matches.size()<<std::endl;


        }  
        int key = cv::waitKey(30);  
        if (key == 27)  
        {  
            return 1;  
        }  
    } 

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to compute the transformation (affine/perspective homography) and transform the image with that. Try `findHomography` opencv function. Compare with this example: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: I have followed your advice but please help me find where did I use incorrectly.I uploaded my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to estimate the position by using algorithms such as [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) or LMeds (Least Median of Squares) that are robust to noise and outliers.

Comment: I have upload my code, please help me to find errors

Comment: You should give us more information... How many matchs do you have ? How many good matches do you have ? What is the homography matrix ? Can you succeed to apply the tutorial that Micka point out with the images from the tutorial ? Do you then try to other images ? You have to debug your code in order to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WarpPerspective() and apply the homography you have found to the two images.